# Why use Pandas.Series over Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: pandas

When should I use `Pandas.Series` over a one column `Pandas.DataFrame`? I feel like the one column dataframe provides more flexibility so maybe it's just an issue of when this flexibility is likely to cause more harm than good? Are there any performance issues I should take into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas.DataFrame "inherits" its structure from Pandas.Series. This means that you are correct in stating that dataframe provides more functionality. The DataFrame has both a row and column index so it can be thought of as a dict of Series (one for all sharing the same index). In terms of advice on what to use in general I find that they are virtually interchangeable and so it is largely a matter of taste and habit.

I would not expect a notable performance difference.